# Git not reflecting changes on live

Tags: git

The way I have my Git repo set up is Workstation -> Production. The user makes their changes, commits them, pushes them, and they are seen on Production. At least that is the way I would like it to be.

According to my research and [this](http://joemaller.com/990/a-web-focused-git-workflow/) article, every is set up like Workstation -> Staging -> Production. Unfortunately, I cannot take this route due to the cost of a new server, and the fact that all of the people working on this project are remote.

My question is: Once changes are committed and pushed to master, how can I make the changes reflect on the website?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: git has nothing to do with building your code or deploying it to production. It's just a VCS. So, you must find a way to trigger build and deploy from git.

Git has a concept of [hooks](http://www.kernel.org/pub//software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html) which may help you in some cases. If you are the maintainer of `Production` repo (I beleive it is repo), just configure `post-receive` hook on it to trigger what you need. But I need to admit that hooks are kind of a low-level solution, where you must write batches for all the actions, you want to perform.

Using [github](https://github.com/) or [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/) is not a problem, just go to `Settings` -> `Service Hooks` (github) or `Administration` -> `Services` (bitbucket) and configure hooks for the repo there. The flaw of this is that you can only trigger a small subset of public services, and it may not work with your Intranet software.

The most powerful approach, IMHO, is to maintain your own [Continuous Integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) server ([Travis CI](https://travis-ci.org/) can fit you in simple cases) and configure it to poll you repo and build release branches automatically (with all the tests you need!) with posterior deploy phase. You will have a full control over the process of releasing the code in this case.

Comment: Awesome, I will definitely look into that and see if it something I can get set up!